# Can a product of conjugates be a Pisot number again?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $p(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial, and let $\alpha_1 \dots, \alpha_n$ be its roots in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $\alpha_1$ is a *[Pisot number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number)*, that is, $\alpha_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \ |\alpha_1| > 1$, and for any $1 < i \leq n$ we have $|\alpha_i| < 1$.

> Suppose that $\alpha_1 < 2$. Is it possible that for some $1 <  k \leq n$ the number $\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_k$ is Pisot?

Note that the assumption that $\alpha_1 < 2$ implies that $\alpha_1 \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)}^*$.

Comment: Do you really mean that the absolute value of a Pisot number is greater than 1, or you want this number to be positive (as in the link you provide)?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I think that the extra condition of positivity you mention is just for normalization. You can always multiply all the roots by minus $1$ to normalize. I am happy with my definition.

Comment: If numbers are considered up to a sign then the last condition should be $|\alpha_1|<2$.

Answer (score 3):

Still, it seems to me that the difference in definitions is not that negligible. But if you are OK with negative numbers --- here is an example.

Set $g(x)=x^2-x$ and $f(x)=g(x)^2-g(x)-1=x^4-2x^3+x-1$. Its roots are the roots of
$$
  g(x)=\frac{1\pm \sqrt5}2.
$$
When the '$+$' sign is chosen, we get two real numbers $\alpha_1\in(1,2)$ and $\alpha_2\in(-1,0)$ since $g(-1)=g(2)>\phi$ but $g(0)=g(1)<\phi$. For the '$-$' sign we have two complex roots whose (equal) absolute values are less than 1 since their product's one is such. Thus $\alpha_1$ is a required example, because $\alpha_1\alpha_2=-\phi$.

**Remark.** I cannot transfom this example into one where the product is a positive Pisot number, and it looks like much more difficult to make, at least with the same method.